# Tortoise SVN conflict occurs but no edit conflict button is shown

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, conflict

I have a conflict when merging a .js file - Tortoise SVN says a conflict occured but no edit conflict button is shown.  What does this mean, and how do I fix it if there is no edit conflict button?

Screenshot of missing edit conflict button:

[image]

Comment: you could delete the local file from the directory (save it first) then do a svn update to get the one on the server...then do a manual comparison with a diff tool

Comment: Yeah I guess so , but if I'm doing manual diff, why do I even have SVN?  This missing button must have a reason, and therefore (I would hope) a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the edit button is disabled, that means that the file in question is not a text file (i.e., has a non-text svn:mime-type property set). In those situations you can not edit the conflict **during** a merge but you have to resolve the conflict manually **after** the merge is done.

The same applies if there's a conflict in properties, not content of a file.

Comment: Thanks - so why would a .js file not be considered a text file, have we set up our repo incorrectly? There was a change in the text, not the properties.

Comment: check the svn:mime-type property on the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the file directly in notepad or your text editor (after choosing resolve later perhaps?). See if there are `>>>>`, `<<<<`, `====` conflict markers (these are standard in SVN for denoting conflicts), and resolve the conflict manually if so.